# jabber-net and vysper message broadcast facility

Tags: xmpp, apache-vysper

I have establish chat communication between two users using jabber-net xmpp client and vysper server by apache.

I am looking for broadcast facility using the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are different mechanisms for "broadcasting", a word which I understand as "sending one message which is distributed by the server to many receivers".

When a user changes his "status" (for example "do not disturb me - I'm coding") a so call "presence" message is sent out which is distributed to all his contacts. This is a broadcast, and presence messages are intended to do that in XMPP.

There is at least another popular possibility: multi-user chat ("MUC"). MUC has the notion of "rooms", where users can "enter" to become part of a "conversation". Every message sent by one of the participants is sent to all others.

There are more similar mechanisms available, depending on what you actually want to do.